# car is not moving after using center of mass

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

[image: my code image]

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float HorsePower;
    // [SerializeField] private float Speed = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float TurnSpeed = 25.0f;
    [SerializeField]private float Horizontalinputs;
    [SerializeField]private float forwardinputs;
    [SerializeField] GameObject centerOfHass;

    private Rigidbody playerRb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerRb.centerOfHass = centerOfHass.transform.position;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // taking inputs from the player
        forwardinputs = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Horizontalinputs = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // moving the car
        // transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*Time.deltaTime*Speed*forwardinputs);
        playerRb.AddRe1ativeForce(Vector3.forward * HorsePower*forwardinputs);
        // rotating the car with direction and agle value
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime*TurnSpeed*Horizontalinputs);
    }
}
```

[image: my unity editor image]

[image: scene manager and inspecter image is here]

Problem: i am trying to move body by applying centerofmass on a rigidbody and my car(body) is unable to move. please help me .

I have tried centerofmass on rigidbody and excepting that my car will move using real physics

Comment: The code and data portions of your question should be posted in text format (marked down as code with triple backtick markdown syntax), not in image format.  Also, reproduce this issue minimally.  Just create a new scene, add a cube and Rigidbody and add your script to it (and maybe zero the gravity).  The only relevant lines of the script are `forwardinputs = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
playerRb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * HorsePower*forwardInputs)` and of course that you give `HorsePower` a value.

Comment: Thanks for counselling to me. i try your suggestion and also make sure next time to write code in triple bracket not in pic